# Regex - Match all numbers after a character

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to find an R command that matches all numbers after the last instance of a certain character.  For instance, let's say I have the following string -

```r
"123_123_abc_123-AB-DC-D4G6"
```

How would I match all numbers after the last "_"?

This is what I want -

```r
gsub("magical regex", "", "123_123_abc_123-AB-DC-D4G6", perl = TRUE)

"123_123_abc_-AB-DC-DG"
```

Comment: This makes no sense, Your last `_` char is between `DC` and `D4G6`

Comment: Edited the post so it makes sense.  Please recommend edits before downvoting as I'm looking for a solution to this.

Comment: How can this still be put on hold as unclear as the current state of the question is clear with an expected result?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It is another "gimme-teh-regex" request: OP showed no effort to solve the task. Since the first two close votes were for unclear, it got closed as unclear.

Comment: I'm with you, @Thefourthbird.  The question as currently stated is clear and your result is what I was looking for.  I put a lot of effort into solving this on my own and could not find a solution to this question after searching extensively through stack.  My hope is that the question will be taken off hold because the solution would prove useful to those implementing regex in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all numbers after the last `_` you could match 1+ digits and make use of a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert no more occurrences of `_`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9nmCO8/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/8h9H69#stdin)

```
gsub("\\d+(?!.*_)", "", "123_123_abc_123-AB-DC-D4G6", perl = TRUE)
```

Result

```
[1] "123_123_abc_-AB-DC-DG"
```

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sharp! I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yep, I see that! Good thing OP fixed their post finally...

Comment: Fixed their post finally?  I initially posted this five minutes ago!  Using a negative lookahead is exactly the solution I was looking for.  Thanks for providing a helpful and non-snarky solution!